# Do allow sorting of sortable items to be placed in unsorted items areas

Tags: mootools

I'm using mootools sortable , here is function below I have to be able to sort some tabs. I have disable a few tabs from sorting , but the other tabs that are allowed to be sorted can be moved into the disable tabs place , can this be stopped? I don't want sortable tabs to be able to be moved to disabled tabs placement at all. Disabled tabs should always remain exactly where they show.

https://jsfiddle.net/1trq9zpz/154/

Is there something similar for mootools ?  I would like to disable #homepagetabs li with class of .disable_sort

```
     var MFLTabSort = new Sortables($('homepagetabs'), { 
         onComplete: function() {
           var parent = this.element.parentNode;
           var saveIt = false;
           if (typeof currentTabOrder == "undefined") {
              currentTabOrder = new Array();
              for (var i = 0; i < parent.getChildren().length; i++) {
                 currentTabOrder[i] = i;
              }
           }
           for (var i = 0; i < parent.getChildren().length; i++) {
              var seqno = parent.getChildren()[i].id.substr("tab".length);
              if (currentTabOrder[i] != seqno) {
                 saveIt = true;
                 currentTabOrder[i] = seqno;
              }
           }
           if (saveIt) {
              var url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/" + year + "/save_setting?L=" + league_id + "&TITLE=TABORDER&VALUE=" + currentTabOrder.join();
              makeHttpRequest(url);
           }
        }
     });       
     MFLTabSort.removeItems($$(".disable_sort"));
```

Comment: I think you could solve it with a better CSS selector. Maybe something like `$('homepagetabs:not(. disable_sort)')`?

Comment: i dont think you can use :not in mootools ? I tried your suggestion and it made the function not work at all

Comment: You can use `:not()` in Mootools, check here: https://mootools.net/core/docs/1.6.0/Slick/Slick#Slick:not Please make a jsFiddle so we can help you more.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1trq9zpz/15/

Comment: In my first comment I missed that you were using the ID selector. Test using `$$('#homepagetabs li:not(.disable_sort)')` instead of `$('homepagetabs')`. If it doesn't work please make the jsFiddle work, it throws errors as it is.

Comment: i made a fiddle , and posted , your suggestion disable all the tabs

Comment: I saw your fiddle, and posted a suggestion: `$$('#homepagetabs li:not(.disable_sort)'` please try it.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1trq9zpz/21/   yes i tried it , but it make the function not work at all , at least for any tab

Comment: i got the sorting to stop on disabled tabs , i updated my question , i need to prevent sortable tabs from taking the place of disabled tabs , so disabled tabs always remain where they show